# Synchronous Call in WSO2 ESB in iterator mediator

Tags: iterator, wso2, call, esb, synchronous

Is there any way to make synchronous call of all the codes written inside the iterator mediator in esb wso2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it is working by doing two things together.
Set sequential="true" in iterator and in call mediator use  blocking = "true"

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use iterator mediator with sequential="true" and call mediator blocking = "true" or "false" upon your requirement both these are synchronous calls. If you want to know more details about call mediator with blocking and non-blocking please refer this  [WSO2 Call (Blocking vs Non-blocking) vs Send Mediators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924300/wso2-call-blocking-vs-non-blocking-vs-send-mediators)

```
<iterate expression="input your array xpath" id="sampleIterator" sequential="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
           // your sequence logic here
            // if call the endpoint in with blocking="true"
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint key="endpoint-name"/>
            </call>

           // if call the endpoint in with blocking="false"
            <call>
                 <endpoint key="endpoint-name"/>
            </call>

        <sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using send mediator? If yes, use call mediator instead, which is synchronous.

Comment: I am using call mediator only..I have also tried setting property  blocking = "true" while calling call mediator but that is also not working.

Comment: Means synchronous call is not happening with call mediator blocking = "true"

Comment: Together with call mediator blocking = "true", I set sequential="true" in iterator then working. Thanks Bhathiya for the help..