# WSO2 Call (Blocking vs Non-blocking) vs Send Mediators

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

what is the difference between call mediator blocking mode and non-blocking mode? according to wso2 docs both are synchronous calls how does these differs. Please help me to understand when to use(real time integration use cases) this call mediator blocking and non-blocking mode. And in what cases send mediator will not fit only call mediator has to be used. I see call = send+respond (in one endpoint case).. what is the bestpractice to use... call or send+respond.. pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct call mediator blocking mode and non-blocking mode both works in a synchronous manner. The call mediator in non blocking mode uses the passthrough transport and therefore has a better performance. Therefore it is recommended to use the call mediator in non blocking mode unless there is a specific requirement to use call mediator in blocking mode.

The significant difference in blocking and non blocking mode is that in the blocking mode the mediation is executed in a single thread. In the non blocking mode the thread will register a callback and that thread is released back to the pool. When a response is received a new thread will pick up the response and proceed the mediation. This will not affect the synchronous processing of mediators in the mediation. Therefore there are some use cases where it is required to execute the mediation in a single thread some of them are as follows,

- In a JMS message processing scenario if you want to rollback the failed messages.
- If you want to process message sequentially within a mediator such as clone mediator, iterate mediator or a message store processor use case. This means that the ESB usually process message parallelly and if you want to avoid this you will need to use blocking calls.

Regarding the send mediator it should be corrected as follows. But it has some differences. When we use a call mediator the insequence the response will come back to the insequence. After the call mediator if we use respond mediator it will respond back to the client.

```
call+respond = send
```

But when we use a send mediator in the insequence the response will come to the outsequence. This is the main functionality difference between the two mediators. Therefore when it comes to how you want to use them it depends on how you want to arrange your mediators. Further the send mediator does not have the capability to configure blocking and non blocking. It functions similar to the non blocking call mediator (in terms of thread utilization).